# Check if some type is instantion of template class std::optional

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

These are template constexpr bools to check if some type is instantiation of `std::optional`

```
template<typename>   constexpr bool is_optional = false;
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>> = true;
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>&> = true;  // avoid this
static_assert(not is_optional<int>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int>>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int>&>);
```

to be exhaustive i need add

```
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>const&> = true;  // avoid this
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>&&> = true;  // avoid this
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional<std::optional<T>const> = true;  // avoid this
```

and possibly volatiles. Looks too cumbersome.

Is there a way to declare only one variable for true case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In c++20, you can use [`std::remove_cv_ref_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref), and a bit of indirection to do this easily:

```cpp
template<typename>   constexpr bool is_optional_impl = false;
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional_impl<std::optional<T>> = true;

template<typename T> 
constexpr bool is_optional = is_optional_impl<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

This will take care of the `const`, `volatile`, and `&` qualifiers.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_gDSTL).

Before c++20, you have to be a little more explicit, like this:

```
template<typename T> 
constexpr bool is_optional = 
  is_optional_impl<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JgIW4k).

Comment: C++11 `template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional = is_optional_impl<std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>>;`

Comment: @kyb I added that to the answer, but you need to remove the `&` before the `cv`s. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bxxCWU)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know if there is a one-line solution using Boost?

Comment: @Evg Do you mean instead of the 3 lines above? I'm not sure, there does some to be at least 2 lines that are irreducible. Maybe there's a utility that returns `true/false` in one line though.

Comment: Something like `is_specialization_of_v<T, std::optional>`. This looks like pretty basic function, but I wasn't able to find anything alike.

Comment: @Evg I think that's just [is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Answer (score 2):

In c++17 you can also use `std::decay_t` instead of `std::remove_cv_ref_t`. Also, you may consider adding a specialization for `std::nullopt_t`.

```
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>   constexpr bool is_optional_impl = false;
template<typename T> constexpr bool is_optional_impl<std::optional<T>> = true;
template<> constexpr bool is_optional_impl<std::nullopt_t> = true;

template<typename T> 
constexpr bool is_optional = is_optional_impl<std::decay_t<T>>;


static_assert(not is_optional<int>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int>>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int>&>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int> const volatile>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::optional<int> const&>);
static_assert(is_optional<std::nullopt_t>);
```