# How do I augment a lambda parameter pack?

Tags: c++, lambda

I want a way to turn, say, this

```cpp
auto a = [](int b, std::string const& c) -> double { ... }
```

into this.

```cpp
auto aa = [](std::variant<int, int> b, std::variant<int, std::string const&> c) -> std::variant<int, double> { ... }
```

I believe variants cannot hold references so it's acceptable if that must instead be this.

```cpp
auto aa = [](std::variant<int, int> b, std::variant<int, std::string> c) -> std::variant<int, double> { ... }
```

It's acceptable if `a` above must be `[](int b, std::string c) -> double` but I suspect `std::remove_reference_t` can solve that.

The above are only examples.  The actual input lambdas might have any return value, including `void`, and any number of parameters, including zero, of any type.  They will be fully concrete in that all types in such lambdas will be known by the time I perform this transformation.

So far, I tried this and several variations.

```cpp
auto add_code = [](auto fn) -> std::variant<int, std::invoke_result_t<decltype(fn)>> {
    return [fn](std::variant<int, auto> ps...) {
        if ((ps.index() != 0 && ...)) {
            return { 0, fn(std::get<1>(ps)...) };
        } else {
            return { 1 };
        }
    };
};
```

If it turns out there is no way to get this to work with a variant, having it work with `std::optional` is acceptable with the
example result being this.

```cpp
auto aa = [](std::optional<int> b, std::optional<std::string> c) -> std::optional<double> { ... }
```

I tried that with variations of this.

```cpp
auto make_optional = [](auto fn) -> std::optional<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(fn)>> {
    return [fn](std::optional<auto> ps...) {
        if ((ps && ...)) {
            return { fn(*(ps)...) };
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    };
};
```

It's acceptable if this needs to be wrapped in a template, perhaps in a struct with `operator()`, or spread across multiple lambdas or templates.  It's also acceptable if the lambdas cannot return `void` or must take at least one parameter.  I can add lambdas to account for these deficiencies.

It doesn't have to be a `std::variant`.  Using `std::pair` or `std::tuple` is also acceptable.

I'm using MSVC but I'd like this to be cross-platform so I'd like it to also work in gcc, clang, or preferably both.  I'm using
C++20 so requiring it is fine.

Comment: I have a hard time to depickle what the actual goal is. If you take the example, `auto aa = [](std::variant<int, int> b, std::variant<int, std::string> c) -> std::variant<int, double> { ... }` - what should happen inside the function body? How would you do it with a regular function template?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it with a regular function template either, that's ok. Just describe, in detail, what you want to happen.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, what's inside the body of `aa` is the return value of `add_code`. I show `aa` only as an example of the expected signature.

Comment: Could you help out in describing _how_? `add_code` is a defined lambda, I see that. I don't see it's intended use.  If you added some examples of input to `aa` and the expected output, maybe it'd "click".

Comment: [Here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/07/07/optional-monad-cpp-without-ugly-stuff/) is something close to what I'd like. It uses `std::optional` which is okay but it uses functions, not lambdas, which is not acceptable.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not going to get help unless you package your question in a way that makes it easy to understand the goal. The link didn't help me to understand what _you_ want. Why is `optional` an ok substitution for `variant`? Why aren't functions acceptable? Why not put together an example that clearly demonstrates the transformation that is supposed to happen inside the lambda body of `aa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439720).  Here is a stripped-down version of that code
that enables me to perform the desired transformation.

```
template <typename...>
struct pack {};

template <typename F, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct parameters {};

template <typename F>
struct parameters<F, std::void_t<decltype(&F::operator ())>> : parameters<decltype(&F::operator ())> {};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Ps>
struct parameters<R(T::*)(Ps...) const> { using type = pack<Ps...>; };

template <typename F>
using parameters_t = typename parameters<std::remove_reference_t<F>>::type;
```

When I first tried to use that code, my compiler complained about not having an unexpanded parameter pack.  That's because I
trimmed the code too much, trying to use only a single function template.  I see now that passing an instance of the parameter pack
from the first function template to the next essentially "unexpands" it and allows the compiler to perform the expansion in the
second function template.

Here is an example of applying it to [this code](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/07/07/optional-monad-cpp-without-ugly-stuff/) I
linked in one of my comments.

```
template <typename F, typename... Ps>
auto make_failable(F&& f, pack<Ps...>) {
    using R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Ps...>;
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](std::optional<Ps>... ps) -> std::optional<R> {
        return (ps && ...) ? f(*(ps)...) : R{};
    };
}

template <typename F>
auto make_failable(F&& f) {
    return make_failable(std::forward<F>(f), parameters_t<F>{});
}
```

More code is required if a lambda already returns `std::optional`.  I first need to detect it using the code given
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62757885).

```
template<typename>
constexpr bool is_optional_impl = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional_impl<std::optional<T>> = true;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_optional = is_optional_impl<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

Then I need two implementations of `make_failable`, one for those already returning `std::optional` and one for those that don't.

```
template <typename F, typename... Ps>
    requires is_optional<std::invoke_result_t<F, Ps...>>
auto make_failable(F&& f, pack<Ps...>) {
    using R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Ps...>;
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](std::optional<Ps>... ps) -> R {
        return (ps && ...) ? f(*(ps)...) : R{};
    };
}

template <typename F, typename... Ps>
    requires (!is_optional<std::invoke_result_t<F, Ps...>>)
auto make_failable(F&& f, pack<Ps...>) {
    using R = std::optional<std::invoke_result_t<F, Ps...>>;
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](std::optional<Ps>... ps) -> R {
        return (ps && ...) ? f(*(ps)...) : R{};
    };
```

Here is some test code to show it in action.  This prints `4815` followed by `no value`.

```
auto f1 = make_failable([](int a) { return a + 1; });
auto f2 = make_failable([](int b, int c) { return b * c; });
auto f3 = make_failable([](int d) { return 2 * d; });
auto f4 = make_failable([](int e) { return e - 1; });
auto result = f4(f3(f2(f1(42), f1(55))));
if (result.has_value()) {
    std::cout << result.value() << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
}
auto f3f = make_failable([](int d) -> std::optional<int> { if (d & 1) return 2 * d; else return {}; });
result = f4(f3f(f2(f1(42), f1(55))));
if (result.has_value()) {
    std::cout << result.value() << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
}
```